# Call to Undefined method Database::lastInsertId()

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I want to insert posts like Worpdress

I use `lastInsertId()` to get `id_post` but I'm getting an error: [Call to Undefined method Database::lastInsertId()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbwBn.png)

This is my code

http://pastebin.com/UzaQBNnU

```
public function savePosts()
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO artikel (id_artikel, judul_artikel, isi_artikel, status, categories) 
            VALUES (NULL, :judul_artikel, :isi_artikel, 'save', :categories_artikel)";
    $stmt = Database::prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':judul_artikel', $this->judul_artikel);
    $stmt->bindParam(':isi_artikel', $this->isi_artikel);
    $stmt->bindParam(':categories_artikel', $this->categories_artikel);
    $stmt->execute();
    return Database::lastInsertId();
}
```

http://pastebin.com/gmj5djgv

```
<?php 

//konstanta Database
define('host', 'localhost');
define('user', 'root');
define('pass', '');
define('db_name', 'cms');


//class Database
class Database
{
    private static $cms;

    public static function getCMS()
    {
        if(!isset(self::$cms)) {
            try {
                self::$cms = new PDO('mysql:host='.host. ';dbname='.db_name, user, pass);
                self::$cms->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                self::$cms->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            }
            catch(PDOException $exception) {
                echo $exception->getMessage();
            }
        }
        return self::$cms;
    }

    public static function prepare($sql)
    {
        return self::getCMS()->prepare($sql);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: post your simplified code here, not links to pastebin code dumps.

Comment: (1) your image says `line 39`, but one of your pastebins has 11 lines, and the other has 36. So your error does not match your code. (2) You have created a `Database` class, but have not created a `lastInsertId()` method, similar to your `public static function getCMS()`

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much what Sean said. Your call to `Database::lastInsertId()` throws an **Undefined method** error because you haven't defined a method `Database::lastInsertId()`. You need to add the definition to your `Database` class the same as you did with `prepare()`:

```
public static function lastInsertId()
{
    return self::getCMS()->lastInsertId();
}
```

Even this may or may not work depending on how (or whether) your database driver implements `PDO::lastInsertId()`.